# How do I shrink a window that exceeds the boundaries of the display?

Tags: window-manager

Using Pycharm on Ubuntu 18.04. The Find/Replace All screens are so large that I cannot see the buttons on the bottom (if there are any).

How do I shrink this? The usual top bar or Minimize buttons do not exist.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Mouse, left button: point it at the gray part between "replace in path" and the checkbox for "match case", hold it  and drag the window to a section of the screen where you do see the bottom right corner edge. Then you should be able to shrink it by moving the bottom right corner.

Comment: Thank you.  This allows me to drag the dialog left and right. But this does not shrink or move the window vertically, so anything at the bottom is still invisible.

Comment: No, you probably need the bottom right corner for that. You can use that to make a window smaller.

Comment: @JoshuaFox resize the top, move the window higher (you can hold the Super/Windows key and drag the window to move it), rinse and repeat.

Comment: I tried to resize this dialog, including iwht the Super/Windows key -- no luck. Maybe it is *meant* to be fixed size and someone it is usable without the extra buttons that I imagine are hidden?